# How to get nested JSON data in Swift 4

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, api, openweathermap

I have made a weather app for iOS in Swift 4, I am using the OpenWeatherMap API to parse the JSON data to the app, I have got most of the app working, where the user inputs a city, and the weather is displayed. I have the current temp, current wind speed, current humidity, and I am trying to get the current description working, but I cannot get it to display.

I want to get the MainLabel to display the current weather description, but I can't get it to work.  At the top of the code is the JSON data from the API key, the description is in the Weather section.  I have tried MainLabel.Weather?.Description but it prints out the entire description, ID, Main, and Icon values.  I would appreciate guidance on it.  Thank you

Here are the structs I use to decode the JSON data from OpenWeatherMap API:

JSON Structs below:

```
import UIKit


//Below is the JSON data from the OpenWeatherMap API


struct Coordinate : Decodable {
    let lat, lon : Double?
}

struct Weather : Decodable {
    var id : Int?
    var main, myDescription, icon : String?

    enum CodingKeys : String, CodingKey {
        case id = "id"
        case main = "main"
        case icon = "icon"
        case myDescription = "description"
    }
}

struct Sys : Decodable {
    let type, id : Int?
    let sunrise, sunset : Date?
    let message : Double?
    let country : String?
}

struct Main : Decodable {
    let temp, tempMin, tempMax : Double?
    let pressure, humidity : Int?
}

struct Wind : Decodable {
    let speed : Double?
    let deg : Int?
}

struct MyWeather : Decodable {
    let coord : Coordinate?
    let cod, visibility, id : Int?
    let name : String?
    let base : String?
    let weather : [Weather]?
    let sys : Sys?
    let main : Main?
    let wind : Wind?
    let dt : Date?
}
```

View controller below:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {



    @IBOutlet weak var HumidityLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var MainLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var WindLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var TempLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var LocationLabel: UILabel!
    //
    @IBOutlet weak var userValue: UITextField!

    //Assigning Labels




    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

            }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    }




    @IBAction func GoButton(_ sender: Any) {

        let text: String = userValue.text!

        guard let APIUrl = URL(string: "https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=" + text +  "&appid=e7b2054dc37b1f464d912c00dd309595&units=Metric") else { return }
        //API KEY

        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: APIUrl) { data, response, error in
            guard let data = data else { return }

            let decoder = JSONDecoder()
            //Decoder

            do {
                let weatherData = try decoder.decode(MyWeather.self, from: data)

                if (self.MainLabel != nil)
                {
                    if let gmain = weatherData.weather?.description {
                        print(gmain)
                        DispatchQueue.main.async {
                            self.MainLabel.text! = String (describing: gmain)
                        }
                    }
                }

                if (self.LocationLabel != nil)
                {
                    if let gmain = weatherData.name {
                        print(gmain)
                        DispatchQueue.main.async {
                            self.LocationLabel.text! = "Current Weather in: " + String (gmain)
                        }
                    }
                }


                if (self.HumidityLabel != nil)
                {
                    if let ghumidity = weatherData.main?.humidity
                    {
                        print(ghumidity, "THIS IS HUMIDITY")
                        DispatchQueue.main.async {
                            self.HumidityLabel.text! = String (ghumidity)
                        }
                    }
                }

                if (self.WindLabel != nil)
                {
                    if let gspeed = weatherData.wind?.speed {
                        print(gspeed, "THIS IS THE SPEED")
                        DispatchQueue.main.async {
                            self.WindLabel.text! = String(gspeed) + " mph"
                        }
                    }
                }

                if (self.TempLabel != nil)
                {
                    if let ggtemp = weatherData.main?.temp {
                        print(ggtemp, "THIS IS THE TEMP")
                        DispatchQueue.main.async {
                            self.TempLabel.text! = String (ggtemp) + " c"
                        }
                    }
                }


            } catch {
                print(error.localizedDescription)
            }
            }.resume()

    }

}
```

Comment: I don't see "description" anywhere in your GoButton code. what do you mean by it doesn't work? It's also unclear why you're using `String (describing:)` here, or `String(...)` at all.  Looking at this code, I would think it would just be `self.HumidityLabel.text = ghumidity` (no `!` and not `String`). Please be careful with naming; variables should have a leading lowercase, not uppercase (i.e. APIUrl should be apiURL and MainLabel should be mainLabel; this can be very important in Cocoa)

Comment: Replace `weatherData.weather?.description` with `weatherData.weather?.first?. myDescription` or find appropriate weather from `weatherData.weather` weather array

Answer (score 1):

Stop and think about these lines:

```
let weatherData = try decoder.decode(MyWeather.self, from: data)
if let gmain = weatherData.weather?.description {
```

If `weatherData` is a MyWeather instance, then its `weather` is a `[Weather]`, because that is how MyWeather is declared:

```
struct MyWeather : Decodable {
    // ...
    let weather : [Weather]?
    // ...
}
```

A `[Weather]` is not a Weather. It is an *array* (of Weather). So you are asking for the `description` of an *array*. And that is just what you are getting.